# Unix Sockets in Go

Tags: sockets, go

I'm trying to make a simple echo client and server that uses Unix sockets. In this example, the connection seems to be unidirectional. The server can receive data from the client, but it can't send the data back. If I use tcp connections instead, it works great. Does anyone know what's wrong?

### Server

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"

func echoServer(c net.Conn) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 512)
        nr, err := c.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        data := buf[0:nr]
        fmt.Printf("Received: %v", string(data))
        _, err = c.Write(data)
        if err != nil {
            panic("Write: " + err.String())
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", "/tmp/echo.sock")
    if err != nil {
        println("listen error", err.String())
        return
    }

    for {
        fd, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            println("accept error", err.String())
            return
        }

        go echoServer(fd)
    }
}
```

### Client

```
package main

import "net"
import "time"

func main() {
    c,err := net.Dial("unix","", "/tmp/echo.sock")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.String())
    }
    for {
        _,err := c.Write([]byte("hi\n"))
        if err != nil {
            println(err.String())
        }
        time.Sleep(1e9)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54):

In your example client, you don't seem to be reading the result from the server. When I add code to do that, I see the results from the server.

Also, take a look at how I used defer and break to make the reader goroutine exit.

### Server

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func echoServer(c net.Conn) {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 512)
        nr, err := c.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        data := buf[0:nr]
        println("Server got:", string(data))
        _, err = c.Write(data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Write: ", err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("unix", "/tmp/echo.sock")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", err)
    }

    for {
        fd, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("accept error:", err)
        }

        go echoServer(fd)
    }
}
```

### Client

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func reader(r io.Reader) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:])
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        println("Client got:", string(buf[0:n]))
    }
}

func main() {
    c, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/echo.sock")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    go reader(c)
    for {
        _, err := c.Write([]byte("hi"))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("write error:", err)
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(1e9)
    }
}
```

Comment: This no longer compiles with the latest version of Go. The `String()` function on the error has been replaced by `Error()` and `net`'s `Dial()` no longer has whatever that second argument was. Here was the suggested edit with the fix that I made but was rejected: https://gist.github.com/nelsonjchen/510ab59caa85251c4709 .