# Go net/http unix domain socket connection

Tags: sockets, http, go

I am having trouble connecting to my server, which listens on a Unix Domain Socket.

Go's `net/http` package doesn't seem to be able to use socket paths to connect to a target.

Is there a good alternative without having to create my own HTTP Protocol implementation using `net`?

---

I found lots of solutions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886719/unix-sockets-in-go), but they are unsuitable

I have tried:

`_, err := http.Get("unix:///var/run/docker.sock")` (changing `unix` to `path`/`socket`. It always complains about an unsupported protocol

Comment: You might find this link usefule: https://gist.github.com/teknoraver/5ffacb8757330715bcbcc90e6d46ac74

This is HTTP client and server implementation someone wrote, I checked it and it works fine, just do small changes like changing the name of the socket to `/var/run/socket.sock`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<strike>You would have to implement your own [RoundTripper](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) to support `unix` sockets.</strike>

The easiest way is probably to just use http instead of unix sockets to communicate with docker.

Edit the init script and add `-H tcp://127.0.0.1:xxxx`, for example:

```
/usr/bin/docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:9020
```

You can also just fake the dial function and pass it to the transport:

```
func fakeDial(proto, addr string) (conn net.Conn, err error) {
    return net.Dial("unix", sock)
}

tr := &http.Transport{
    Dial: fakeDial,
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
resp, err := client.Get("http://d/test")
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/6pTJDgIPKX)

There's only one tiny caveat, all your `client.Get` / `.Post` calls has to be a valid url (`http://xxxx.xxx/path` not `unix://...`), the domain name doesn't matter since it won't be used in connecting.

Comment: @matejkramny I added a tip about just using http instead.

Comment: Awesome! I was going to point out you can register a protocol implementation (http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.RegisterProtocol), but this is way easier! Thx

Comment: @matejkramny using RegisterProtocol you'd have to pretty much copy/paste `DefaultTransport.RoundTrip` and modify it to use `unix`.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a few years since this question was asked and answered, but I came across it while looking for the same thing. I also found the [httpunix](https://godoc.org/github.com/tv42/httpunix) package which addresses this problem expertly.It also supports registering a new protocol so you can use native URLs such as **http+unix://service-name/.....**. Worked quite nicely for me.